# By using laws of algebra of statements show that p or (p and q) is equivalent to p .

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I verified the above result using truth tables and got that the LHS is equivalent to the RHS, but I am not able to prove the result using the laws of the algebra of statements.  Please guide me.

Comment: Use the distributive property.

Comment: Hint: $p\vee(p\wedge q)\equiv (p\wedge T)\vee(p\wedge q)$.  Then use the distributive property.

Comment: I don't think this question should have been closed, at least not for the reason given. It's perfectly clear what the question is: "I solved this by one method, but how do I do it with this other method?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is to recall that $p\equiv p\wedge T$ by the identity property.  Substituting this into the expression gives

> $$p\vee(p\wedge q)\equiv (p\wedge T)\vee(p\wedge q)$$.

Next, using the distributive law, we have

> $$\equiv p\wedge(T\vee q)$$.

Then, using the identity property twice,

> $$\equiv p\wedge T\equiv p$$.